# mongodb user not being updated

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

```
export const editProfile = (req,res) => {
    
try{
    userModel.find({username:req.body.username},(err,user)=>{
       if (user.length !== 0) {
        if (typeof(req.body.nusername) === "undefined"){
            console.log("error")
        }else{
            const filter = {new:true}
         
            const opts = { new: true };
            console.log(filter)
           userModel.findOneAndUpdate({ username: req.body.username }, { $set: { username:req.body.nusername} }, opts)
        
            const token = jwt.sign({username:req.body.nusername,password:user.password,email:user.email,bio:user.bio,profileImg:user.profileImg},"Secret123")
         
           
                res.status(208).json({token:token})
        
            
        }
       }
    })

    
    
    

}catch(err){
    
}
}
```

its not updating the user in my mongodb database i dont know what im doing wrong
is there anything in the code i am doing incorrect?

Comment: In order to prevent [NoSQL-Injection](https://blog.websecurify.com/2014/08/hacking-nodejs-and-mongodb.html) you may use library [mongo-sanitize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-sanitize) or use at least `find({username: JSON.stringify(req.body.username)})`

Answer (score 0):

You need use async await!

```
export const editProfile = (req,res) => {
    
try{
    await userModel.find({username:req.body.username},async (err,user)=>{
       if (user.length !== 0) {
        if (typeof(req.body.nusername) === "undefined"){
            console.log("error")
        }else{
            const filter = {new:true}
         
            const opts = { new: true };
            console.log(filter)
           await userModel.findOneAndUpdate({ username: req.body.username }, { $set: { username:req.body.nusername} }, opts)
        
            const token = jwt.sign({username:req.body.nusername,password:user.password,email:user.email,bio:user.bio,profileImg:user.profileImg},"Secret123")
         
           
                res.status(208).json({token:token})
        
            
        }
       }
    })

    
    
    

}catch(err){
    
}
}
```